# error parsing getopt parameters

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

When I try to run the script as below:

*./myscript.sh --certtype ca --password xyz --commonname xyz*

I get the following error:

```
+ local BIN_PATH CertType Password Commonname
+ BIN_PATH=keytool
++ getopt -u -o t:p:c -l certtype:password:commonname -- --certtype ca     --password xyz --commonname xyz
getopt: unrecognized option '--password'
getopt: unrecognized option '--commonname'
+ options=' --certtype:password:commonname -- ca xyz xyz'
+ echo 'Error on parsing parameters'
Error on parsing parameters
+ exit 1
```

Below is the script I am trying to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

main()
{
   set -x
   local BIN_PATH CertType Password Commonname 
   BIN_PATH="keytool"
   if ! options=$(getopt -u -o t:p:c:: -l certtype:password:commonname:: -- "$@")
      then
      # something went wrong, getopt will put out an error message for us
         echo "Error on parsing parameters"
         exit 1
   fi  

   set -- $options

   while [ $# -gt 0 ] 
   do
      case "$1" in
       -t | --certtype) CertType="$2" ; shift;;
       -p | --password) Password="$2" ; shift;;
       -c | --commonname) Commonname="$2" ;shift;;
       -- ) shift; break;;
       -* ) echo "$0: error - unrecognized option $1" 1>&2; exit 1;; 
       *  ) break;;
      esac
      shift
   done

   echo "Cert type is: $CertType"
   echo "Password is: $KeystorePassword"
   echo "common name is: $CommonName"
}
main "$@"
```

Am I missing anything in the code above?

Thanks,
Firas

Comment: By the way: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks Pierre but I think a colon is needed after each option since a value is read for each of these option flags.

Comment: @F.K.: sorry: I just saw my mistake, but didn't have time to correct it.

Comment: @F.K.: In that case, you need also a colon (and only one) after the last c: `t:p:c:`

Comment: Crucial to do use eval and quotes to properly handle arguments with spaces: `eval set -- "$options"`

Comment: And a previous comment has been deleted: you need commas in the --long option: `-l certtype:,password:,commonname::`

Comment: @Pierre: Thanks. I changed the code and updated the question with my changes but still same issue.

Comment: Also, you declare common name as optional but you don't have a default value for it.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks. Testing. I will update with results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

main()
{
   set -x
   local BIN_PATH CertType Password Commonname 
   BIN_PATH="keytool"
   # add commas between the long options
   if ! options=$(getopt -u -o t:p:c: -l certtype:,password:,commonname: -- "$@")
      then
      # something went wrong, getopt will put out an error message for us
         echo "Error on parsing parameters"
         exit 1
   fi  

   set -- $options

   while [ $# -gt 0 ] 
   do
      case "$1" in
       -t | --certtype) CertType="$2" ; shift;;
       -p | --password) Password="$2" ; shift;;
       -c | --commonname) Commonname="$2" ;shift;;
       -- ) shift; break;;
       -* ) echo "$0: error - unrecognized option $1" 1>&2; exit 1;; 
       *  ) break;;
      esac
      shift
   done

   echo "Cert type is: $CertType"
   # correct the two variable names below
   echo "Password is: $Password"        # was $KeystorePassword
   echo "common name is: $Commonname"   # was $CommonName
}
main "$@"
```

Comment: Pierre and Glenn, thank you so much! It was the missing commas in the long names as you both pointed out.

Comment: Pierre, I accepted your solution. Thanks for your help.